# Using Google's Cloud Storage with iOS, is there a proper documentation?

Tags: ios, file-upload, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to use Google's Cloud Storage with my iOS app, and after many hours of headaches and scrolling I have finally been able to add the GTL-library to my project. I don't understand why they couldn't just make it a "Google.framework" or something, I actually had to download an example project, and snatch the files. I added the Objective-C Google service "Storage" to my application, but I can't find any documentation on how to use it to upload files to my my Cloud Storage. The only documentation I found for Objective-C and was [this](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/wiki/Introduction), and it only shows a very limited numbers of examples, and lots of information missing.

As I said, I am trying to *upload* files to my Google Cloud Storage, but the only mentioning of "Uploading files" in this "documentation" is using `GTLDriveFile` from the API using Google Drive, and I'm not using that. I need something similar for Google Cloud Storage, but there's simply no documentation to be found. I might be incredibly tired and my googling-skills are weary, but I can't for the life of me find out anything at all on the subject of uploading files from an iOS app to a Google Cloud Storage account. Has anybody had any luck regarding this? I can't even get much out of `GTLStorage.h` and the rest of the files. I didn't find any good comments in the files at all. I haven't read them all, but I don't really feel I should have to.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is from a while back, but if you're still interested, here is a [sample for accessing Google Cloud Storage from iOS in Objective-C](https://github.com/google/google-api-objectivec-client-for-rest/tree/master/Examples/StorageSample).

Additionally, I found a [sample for accessing Google Cloud Storage via Swift](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/abelana/blob/master/iOS/Abelana_v2/CloudStorage.swift).